# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following the basic tutorial in order to create an e-mail / password authentication using `Firebase`.

```
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
 });
```

But whenever I try to create an account (with a valid e-mail address and a diversity of passwords, with caps, numbers, high length) it displays my failure `Toast`.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: are you testing this in an emulator?

Comment: No, I am testing it on a Samsung Galaxy S4

Comment: does that phone have google services enabled and updated?

Comment: @ChristopherK., could you debug your app and tell me the value of `mAuth`?

Comment: @ChristopherK., are you getting and parsing to String the email and password? `email.getText().toString()` and `password.getText().toString()`

Comment: When a `Task` fails, it has a reason for that failure in the result. You're ignoring that reason in your code. I recommend [adding an `onFailureListener` and logging/raising the exception](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnFailureListener), which will tell you *why* the user creation is failing.

Comment: Just a suggestion, have you checked to see if the account has actually been created already and the email is currently in use?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427322/4815718) contains example code for getting the failure reason.

Comment: @Jaco: `mAuth` contains a `zzbkg` object. And I do parse then `toString()`.

I receive the following reason of failure: 

> onComplete: Failed=An internal error has occurred. [ OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED ] EDIT: And I do have the e-mail address / password permission in the console active.

Answer (score 2):

As this answer says: [Firebase Android: An internal error has occurred. [ OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816014/firebase-android-an-internal-error-has-occurred-operation-not-allowed)

You need to have the authentication method enabled in the Firebase console, so go to the authentication option on Firebase and then, to the sign in method to activate the email provider.

I Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Go to Firebase console -> Authentication -> SIGN-IN METHOD -> enable Email/Password**

[image]