# Android: Firebase authentication with Facebook failing

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to use Firebase to handle authentication with Facebook logins. I've created the activity by following the documentation on both Firebase's and Facebook's sites and making sure the settings on both sites are filled as needed.

I'm able to log in to Facebook from my app, but when it comes to Firebase saving the user, I get an error:

> signInWithCredential com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An
>   internal error has occurred. [ Access Not Configured. Google Identity
>   Toolkit API has not been used in project 27973105972 before or it is
>   disabled. Enable it by visiting https ]

On Firebase I have for Sign-in providers: Facebook enabled with correct App ID and App secret.

On Facebook I have added the Firebase's redirect URI to the Valid OAuth redirect URIs list.

As a note, searching for Google Identity Toolkit API, leads me to https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/ where it says to use Firebase Authentication. So not a very helpful error message.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // [START auth_state_listener]
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication successful 2.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication signed out.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // ...
            }
        };
        // [END auth_state_listener]

        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "facebook onCancel",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "facebook onError",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ...
            }
        });
        // [END initialize_fblogin]
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // [START on_start_add_listener]
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // [START on_stop_remove_listener]
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // [START auth_with_facebook]
    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication successful.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your query has been resolved by now.

In my case following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816014/firebase-android-an-internal-error-has-occurred-operation-not-allowed) did the trick. All you have to do is make sure that you have enabled the appropriate sign-in method.

- Go to your Firebase console
- Select the chosen app
- (As of this date)
- Click on Authentication (on the left side)
- Select sign-in method
- Enable desired method
- Check this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login) for complete details for Java code

Your code seems sound to me.